# Minecraft Summing Blocks/Skulls

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to summon a Skeleton Skull using:

```
/summon Item ~ ~ ~ {ItemId:skull}
```

While the item is summoned, I cannot pick it up, and when I throw another skull at it, both skulls disappear. I am confused, is it my command or is it Minecraft?

Answer (score 2):

The `Count` tag of the item format will default to 0 when not defined, creating a ghost item that will indeed vanish under certain circumstances.

As such you'll need to specify a `Count`. Your NBT data is also incorrect; item data for item entities is stored within an `Item` compound, with the ID of the item stored within it as the `id` tag:

```
/summon Item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:"minecraft:skull",Count:1b}}
```

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea that you had to add count to summoning items. Also, thank you for the fixed format, although my format does work on other items.(I had to add the count part you mentioned).

Answer (score -1):

just if you can use gmc open the inventory and find a skull. if you cant but can do commands use the /give command and find the item id for it on google.

Comment: "Use the command" is not an answer on a question asking "Why doesn't this command work?" And I have no idea what "gmc" is supposed to be.

Comment: @MrLemon gmc is Gamemode Creative, just to help out there. And greenbueller it isn't the fact I want a skull, its that I want to summon the item to a certain plate. Thanks anyways.